# C++ cryptic operator overloading declaration

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Recently I have come across the following:

```
    ostream& ostream::operator<<(ostream& (*func)(ostream&))
{
    return (*func)(*this);
    }
```

I could not understand the parameter and return statement. It would be great if can be explained with another meaningful example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ostream& (*func)(ostream&)
```

This declares a pointer-to-function named `func`.  The pointed-to function is declared to accept an `ostream&` argument, and to return an `ostream&`.

```
(*func)(*this)
```

This expression invokes the pointed-to function, passing `*this` (an `ostream&`) as the argument, and returning the result of the function invocation.

So if you had the following function:

```
ostream & print_one(ostream &s) {
    return s << '1';
}
```

Then the operator implementation in your question would allow you to do:

```
some_ostream << print_one;
```

As syntactic sugar that essentially means the same thing as:

```
print_one(some_ostream);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/):

> ostream& operator<< (ostream& (*pf)(ostream&));
>
> A function that takes and returns a stream object. It generally is a manipulator function.

This allows you to use a number of built-in manipulator functions like `endl`, so `cout << endl` actually calls `endl(cout)` ([docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/endl/)):

> `endl`: Inserts a new-line character and flushes the stream.

There are a number of other built-in manipulator functions, but `endl` is by far the most common like. Apart from that, as cdhowie mentioned, this is just syntactic sugar.